# Correct response on a request for multiple objects where one does not exist

Tags: http, get

What is the correct response on a GET request for multiple objects where one or more of them does not exist? e.g.:

```
http://example.net/event-list/?ids=1&ids=5&ids=3
```

where object with id 5 does not exist. Should I return a list with just objects 1 and 3 or should I return some kind of error? What is the correct response?

Also I wonder If the behaviour should be any different if the request is POST. For instance:

```
$.post('example.net/events/bulk-edit/?ids=1&ids=5&ids=3', { public: true });
```

Should I just perform operation for the objects that exist or do not perform operation at all and return an error?

I know there are some debates if non-empty querystrings are ok for POST requests. I think they are alright just for this particular case where you request a subset of objects to do something with them.

Comment: Would be interesting to know of which type the response would be. Is it HTML, JSON, XML or something entirely different?

Comment: It is all three. I have unified logic for filtering objects based on querystring params (backend forms). This logic can either say the params are invalid in which case I should return an error of some sort or it can be valid in which case I return the requested objects. So the question is if `ids=1&ids=5&ids=3` is invalid if one of the objects does not exist or if it should be considered valid, in which case I should return just the two existing objects without notifying user or a remote system that he has requested an invalid id.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I gave it some thoughts and here is what I believe were the right thing to do.

This is a bit of a headache since you're requesting multiple objects at once which is usually a WebDAV-thing, bringing wonders such as the `207/Multistatus` response with it. Let me start of with saying that I think your query string has the wrong format. I think it really should look like this:

```
?ids[]=1&ids[]=5&ids[]=3
```

Now about responses on a `GET` request. I believe the following response codes were the right ones:

- 200 if *any* object could be found by id
- 400 on a missing or empty `ids` query parameter (unless you think no `ids` should translate into *get all objects*)
- 404 if *none* of the given ids match any object

If you want to notify the client that the request couldn't be satisfied in parts, you are free to send a `Warning` header along (cf [RFC 2616, sec 14.46](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.46)). However, if you really want to do it absolutely right™, here's how to deal with requests where not every id is valid:

- If *all* ids could be used to load an object, send the `200/Ok` response code
- If there are *any* ids that could not be used to load an object, redirect via `301/Moved Permanently` to a new URL sans the offending `ids` param(s)

As for the `POST` request: It is my understanding that you'd like to set multiple events as public in one go? If so, I'd really change the order: Send a `POST` to `http://domain.net/events/publish` and send the ids in the post body.

Comment: Thank you. Btw it does not need to look like this: ?ids[]=1&ids[]=5&ids[]=3. That is a practice just for some frameworks. E.g. Django framework doesn't use the square-bracket syntax.